# Decomposition of U1 gate $U_1(\lambda)$ , Phase Shift gate $\phi(\delta) $, and Swap gate

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, gate-synthesis

Can we express U1 gate $U_1(\lambda)$ , Phase Shift gate $\phi(\delta) $, and Swap gate

$$ U_1(\lambda) =  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\lambda}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$     \phi(\delta) =  \begin{pmatrix}e^{i\delta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\delta}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ SWAP =  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 &0& 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &1  \end{pmatrix}$$

in terms of the following gates

$$ R(\theta, \phi) =  \begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} & -ie^{-i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \\ -ie^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2} & \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ R_x(\theta) =  \begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} & -i\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \\ -i\sin\frac{\theta}{2} & \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ R_y(\theta) =  \begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} & -\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2} & \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ R_z(\theta) =  \begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ H =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ Z = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ XX = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\chi & 0 & 0 & -i\sin\chi \\ 0 & \cos\chi & -i\sin\chi & 0 \\ 0 & -i\sin\chi & \cos\chi & 0 \\ -i\sin\chi & 0 & 0 & \cos\chi \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ CNOT = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ CZ = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \alpha-Swap = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ 0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

If yes, then please give the decomposition.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also do you care about a global phase?

Comment: Yes, global phase is required.

Comment: @quankid, this sounds like homework/coursework, which is not prohibited on this site, but you haven't motivated your question or explained what you've done.  Please consider editing your question to provide details.  It also helps to remember punctuation - what is your question? is better than what is your question.

Answer (score 1):

In general (except from very specific angles), you cannot make $U_1$ or $\phi$ from rotation gates $R_x,R_y,R_z$, nor from $H$ or $Z$ as these gates have determinant $\pm1$, and $U_1(2\lambda)$ and $\phi(\lambda)$ have determinant $e^{2i\lambda}$ .

$\mathrm{SWAP}$ can be easily made from three $\mathrm{CNOT}$s, try it yourself.

Comment: Can swap be made from alpha-Swap?

Comment: @quankid With only $\alpha-\mathrm{SWAP}$ alone does not seem to be possible.